# Error System Service Not available before oncreate

Tags: java, android

I am calling checkinternet connection method. Code of java class having checkinternet method is below.

```
   public class PTs {

    private Context context;

    public PT(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Boolean checkinternet() {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeinternet = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeinternet != null && activeinternet.isConnected();

    }
```

whereas i am using if statement as below to get internet status in other activity.

```
if (pt.checkinternet()){
//do some task
}
```

Why getting error?can someone help.

Comment: Please show how you are getting the `pt` object.

Comment: public class StartupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PT pt = new PT();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//rest of code for class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never** create an instance of an activity, service, or provider yourself through a constructor. The activity is not properly initialized, and so you cannot call `getSystemService()` on it.

Options to fix this include:

- Move this code into an existing activity, one that is started properly by the framework, and only use that method from within that activity
- Remove `extends AppCompatActivity` from `PT` and have `checkinternet()` take a `Context` as a parameter

Comment: public class PT {

    public Boolean checkinternet(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeinternet = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeinternet != null && activeinternet.isConnected();

    } with these correction still get error in getSystemService. Anything i left to mention.

Comment: Also updated calling code as (performanceTweaks.checkinternet(StartupActivity.this))

Comment: @AnkurJain: Presumably you are calling `checkinternet()` before `onCreate()` of `StartupActivity` is called.

Comment: i am very new to this, if u can provide correct way of coding, it will be really useful.

Comment: got the issue, i was writting getsystemservice instead of context.getsystemservice. It is working.